# Searching Installed Apps Marshmallow 6.0.1

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, search

I installed an OTA update today on my Moto X Play which supposedly addressed some security issues. The install went smoothly with no obvious hiccups during the process however after the update and reboot some apps do not show up in search results for locally installed applications.

For example, I used the eBay app this morning. I opened it the same way I normally would if it wasn't in my recent apps list by going to the apps menu and searching "ebay" then selecting the result. After the update, there is no result, but I can scroll down to find it manually.

I also noticed that at least one app (Firefox in this case) that had a shortcut on my homescreen is also unsearchable, and that it's shortcut had been removed.

Both these apps open no problem, and I was able to re-create the shortcut for Firefox which is functional.

I'm not aware of a way to rebuild a search DB, and after some Googling I wasn't able to find anything other than the suggestion to try clearing the partition cache, or if that fails to restore to factory settings and install apps from scratch.

I figured there was no harm in clearing said cache but I'm not keen on doing a complete wipe and restore.

**TL;DR
Local search is broken.**

Is there some sort of search DB/cache that I can trigger a rebuild of? Is this something that can be done in-phone or are there some adb commands I can issue to do this?

Comment: After searching to get some information on the app install process, it looks like each app puts an entry in a file called packages.list, specifically a line in that file:

`com.android.quicksearchbox 10033 0 /data/data/com.android.quicksearchbox`

which I'm guessing is what somehow got messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Search is working again on my phone. It seems the system rebuilds an index of sorts on its own, I just had to be more patient.

Marking as answer in case someone else has the same experience and hasn't waited a day for the indexing to finish.